# Why do I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in my JDBC connection?

Tags: java, jdbc, unidata, universe

I am new to Java and I am attempting to use JDBC to connect to an UniVerse database. I'm using Sun Java 6 JDK to using NetBeans to build the project. My simple test below builds however it gives the errors below:

```
> run:
driver loaded
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Connecting...
        at com.ibm.u2.jdbc.UniJDBCProtocolU2Impl.initDefaultMarks(UniJDBCProtocolU2Impl.java:1239)
        at com.ibm.u2.jdbc.UniJDBCProtocolU2Impl.<init>(UniJDBCProtocolU2Impl.java:116)
        at com.ibm.u2.jdbc.UniJDBCConnectionImpl.<init>(UniJDBCConnectionImpl.java:137)
        at com.ibm.u2.jdbc.UniJDBCDriver.connect(UniJDBCDriver.java:111)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:207)
        at testjdbc.Main.main(Main.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
        at asjava.uniclientlibs.UniTokens.<clinit>(UniTokens.java:109)
        ... 7 more
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

My Test Code:

```
/*
* To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/

package testjdbc;
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;

 /**
 *
* @author norm
 */
public class Main {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Connection con = null ;

    try{
        // generate URL

    String url = "jdbc:ibm-u2://my.uv.db:31438/DB-ACCOUNT;user=me;password=pass"; //testing, I remove user and password from here and use them below. Still FAILS!!! ARGGGG!!!
    String user = "me";
    String password = "pass";

    String driver = "com.ibm.u2.jdbc.UniJDBCDriver";
    //Load driver and connect to server
    Class.forName(driver);
    System.out.println("driver loaded");
    System.out.println("Connecting...");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url); //This is line 36
    // con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password); // gives the same error
    //con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ibm-u2://my.uv.db:31438/D:/PathTo/DB;" ); //and yet the same error for this as well
    System.out.println("Connection String sent");
    System.out.println("Querying...");
    testQuery( con ) ;

    }
    catch ( SQLException e ) {
        System.out.println("Ex-Message :" + e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Ex-Code    :" + e.getErrorCode()) ;
        System.out.println("Ex-SQLState:" + e.getSQLState());
        System.out.println("Ex-Next    :" + e.getNextException());
        e.printStackTrace() ;
        System.gc();
  } catch ( Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception caught:"+e) ;
        e.printStackTrace() ;
  }
}

public static void testQuery(Connection con)
    throws SQLException
{
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    String sql = "select FIRST.NAME from EMPCEL";
            //"select @ID, CITY, STATE, ZIP, PHONE from CUSTOMER";

    // Execute the SELECT statement
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

    // Get result of first five records
    System.out.println("\tlist selected columns for the first five records:");
    int i = 1;
    while (rs.next() && i < 6)
    {
        System.out.println("\nRecord "+ i +" :");
        System.out.println("\tFirst Name : \t" + rs.getString(1));
//            System.out.println("\tCITY :\t" + rs.getString(2));
//            System.out.println("\tSTATE :\t" + rs.getString(3));
//            System.out.println("\tZIP : \t" + rs.getString(4));
//            System.out.println("\tPHONE :\t" + rs.getString(5));
        i++;
        System.out.println("Finished.");
    }

    rs.close();
    stmt.close() ;
    System.out.println("\n\t*--- QUERY test is done successful ---*\n");
}

}
```

Comment: Ass you can see, I have tried the DriverManager.getConnection a few different ways, including some that are not reflected in this iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be Netbeans related. See also [this topic](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic15178.html) at their forum. It appears to work in Eclipse (and possibly all other environments).

This is clearly a bug in the UniVerse JDBC driver. It is apparently inside the static initializer relying on some specific environmental condition, which is different in Netbeans. If it wasn't a bug, it would have thrown a much more self-explaining exception, not such a silly runtime exception.

I'd report this bug to IBM/UniVerse.

Comment: HOLY CRAP!!! That was it. And to think I was banging my head against the desk all day yesterday over this. I am so going to be on the phone with Rocket about this. Thank you BalusC!! And Thank you Stackoverflow. 

I guess this settles the debate over which IDE I'll be using.

Answer (score 1):

If the presented code is the one that actually caused the exception, then I guess, it fails because `url` is `null` at the time you try to get the connection.

But the error stacktrace shows an error at line 36 which is comment line. So if my guess is wrong, please edit your question and present matching code and error message and mark the line of code that throws the exception.

---

You're not alone: [same problem](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic15178.html)

Comment: I edited the code to further explain what I have tried on the various lines. Thanks for the reply. I have also used the ip address as well as the domain name. Still no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this problem too.  UniTokens is assuming that there is a one-for-one conversion of bytes to chars, but it is not true for all platforms.  Passing an argument to the JVM avoids this issue.  Try -Dfile.encoding="windows-1252" or -Dfile.encoding="US-ASCII"